# Force date format regardless of culture

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, currentuiculture

I have an issue with certain cultures (Spanish in particular), causing the date string, ToShortDateString(), to come in as dd/mm/yyyy

```
where END_DATE between '" + asOfDate.AddDays(-30).ToShortDateString() + "' and '" +
```

This is causing SQL sever errors because we get incorrect date literal strings such as this:

```
where END_DATE between '17/05/2015' and '16/06/2015'
```

What is the best way to force the date format to be mm/dd/yyyy in these cases, where I am building a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that if you are going to use *any* format then make sure its an ISO-type format such as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
where END_DATE between '" + asOfDate.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and
```

However, the far more important point is use parameterised queries, not string concatenation. When you do this, a date is a date is a date and format is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that we should be using parameterized queries. This code is old and needs to be updated at some point.I like the simplicity of your solution.  I just tried the following and it works, albeit more wordy than your suggestion: ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)

Comment: @Slinky - I never suggested that.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cultures: try "SET DATEFORMAT dmy" and try to set a date to '2014-12-31'.  The format to use that is culture-independent is YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
asOfDate.AddDays(-30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

(note the uppercase MM)